# Can you put a Literal as part of a hyperlink?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hyperlink, literals

So my codebehind looks like this and is working correctly as text.  But I need to add the value to a hyperlink

```
If pt.SelectedValue = "1" Then
litTier.Text = "/link.aspx"
Else
litTier.Text = "link2.aspx"
End If
```

My hyperlink currently looks like this

```
<a href='/link.aspx' onclick="return newWindow2('/link.aspx','300','300');">
```

When I add the literal
     
in place of /link.aspx I get the error 'Text' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor'.

Comment: Please read your post and ask yourself whether anyone not sharing your mind can understand the issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: I tried replacing /link.aspx with <asp:Literal ID="litTier" runat="server"></asp:Literal> and I get error "'Text' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor'."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a hyperlink aspx server control, not any literal control

Ex:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hyp1" NavigateUrl="/link.aspx" 
 OnClientclick="return newWindow2('/link.aspx','300','300');" runat="server"/>
```

Then in your codebehind

```
If pt.SelectedValue = "1" Then
hyp1.NavigateUrl = "/link.aspx"
Else
hyp1.NavigateUrl = "link2.aspx"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I add the literal in place of /link.aspx I get the error 'Text'
>   is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor'.

The error message (as you might expect) is correct: `Text` is not an available property. Use `InnerText` or `InnerHtml` instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor_properties(v=vs.80).aspx

But it sounds like you have more problem(s). For example, where's this literal?

You should:

- declare a hyperlink in your markup using `<asp:Hyperlink>` or `<a runat="server">`
- set the URL using the appropriate property
- set the text using the appropriate property
- set other client-side attributes (like `onclick`) using the Attributes collection

Comment: You make many good points, thank you so much for your time.

    <asp:Hyperlink runat="server"><asp:Literal ID="litTier" runat="server"></asp:Literal></asp:Hyperlink> is how it is right now and the error is now 'InnerText' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal'.

I'm sorry I'm completely new and trying to get a handle on inhereted code.